# Magento 1.5.1: "Image does not exist" while importing products

Tags: magento, import, product, magento-1.5, dataflow

I’ve always use this method to import products with images:
- putting all the images to import in “/media/import”;
- add “/image_name.jpg” to image column in the csv file to import;

Since magento 1.5.1 this method stop working.
I always get “Image Does not exist!”.
Do anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell what is happening there but I would check relevant code with xdebug to verify that image path which is used is correct, directory permissions are good, etc

Comment: I don't know how it is, but while I was trying to debug, the import started to work again. Magento leaves me perplexed every time.